# Allowing the contract owner to recover tokens

Tags: tokens

Say the contract owner sends some tokens to address A. Is there a way for the contract owner to later recover those tokens without involving A? What functions would be involved?

advise appreciated

Comment: The ERC-20 standard doesn't have the ability to recover tokens sent to the contract itself. But I wrote a simple contract that can do that - check it out! [Erc20Recover](https://github.com/paulrberg/contracts/blob/221f008dd8f4e377b9a58d9caaf4e562b7589b3f/contracts/token/erc20/Erc20Recover.sol).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's not. If the token contract uses the typical ERC20 implementation, there is no function that would allow the token's original owner to recover them once transferred. The only way to recover them is to have A send them back if you can somehow reach out to them.

Comment: okay, I see. It appears that you could destroy the tokens A is holding though. A function which seems to be used by bancor https://medium.com/unchained-reports/bancor-unchained-all-your-token-are-belong-to-us-d6bb00871e86

Comment: It really depends on each particular contract. If a function to do was not implemented in the contract, then there's nothing you could do. Also, if every token contract allowed for that, no one would buy them, knowing the original owner can take the tokens from them...

Comment: yes, but say you wanted to use the ledger to store data that needs to be manipulated by a single admin/owner.